# Auto calculate input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 `input` fields, one input and the other is disabled. I need when input numbers in the input fiend, the disabled field to show this `number/100`. I try to use `<span>` with this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sum').keyup(function(){
        $('#result').text($('#sum').val() / 100);
    });   
});
```

But it didn't work. 
This is my input fields:

```
<input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" value="php" size="15" />
<input type="text" name="result" id="result" size="15" value="HERE THE RESULT" disabled />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [val()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp) instead of [text()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp).

Another point is to check for `division by zero` error just to be safe. Here is what your code should be.

```
$('#sum').keyup(function(){
    var res = $('#sum').val() / 100;
    if (res == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || res == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || isNaN(res))
        res = "N/A"; // OR 0
    $('#result').val(res);
});
```

Comment: Okey, another question.. how to call this functions in the both fields? So they can send result and show results... (i dont know javascript very much)

Comment: You mean the function should fire when any of the field changes?

Comment: In the first field i input numbers, in the moment i input number i need this numbers to be calculated /100 and to show the result in the second field, witch is disabled, where is "HERE THE RESULT" there i need to show the result in the field, but i dont know how to pu the result from the js there...

Comment: Try the code in the answer and check if it works. You are using jquery code so make sure that you have imported jquery library before using the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use val() not text() for input field.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sum').keyup(function(){
            $('#result').val($('#sum').val() / 100));
        });   
    });
```